# Obtener solo un campo de un web API que entrega varios campos

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. En el aplicativo que estamos desarrollando, estamos consumiendo el siguiente web API:

```
/// <summary>
    /// 2024-02-05: Se obtiene los campos por cada registro de salida de llantas.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Registro">Registro que permite individualizar los datos.</param>
    /// <returns>Todos los campos por registro.</returns>
    [HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registro", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistro")]
    public List<LlanSalidasLlantas> GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(int Registro)
    {
        try
        {
            var q = from a in context.LlanSalidasLlantas
                    where a.Registro == Registro
                    select new LlanSalidasLlantas
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                        cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                        familia = a.familia,
                        fecha = a.fecha,
                        codigo = a.codigo,
                        descripcion = a.descripcion,
                        tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                        tipo = a.tipo,
                        numero = a.numero,
                        cantidad = a.cantidad,
                        costo = a.costo,
                        total_costo = a.total_costo,
                        destino = a.destino,
                        horometro = a.horometro,
                        adicional = a.adicional,
                        horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                        empresa = a.empresa
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return LlanSalidasLlantasExcepcion;
        }
    }
```

De este web API, solo necesitamos el campo equipo. Con este campo, vamos a realizar un CustomValidator de la siguiente forma:

```
/// <summary>
/// 2024-02-23: Valida si el IdLlanta que se desmonta, estaba en dicha ubiciación.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <param name="args"></param>
protected void CVUbicacionLlanta_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    //Datos cliente
    string IdLlanta = TBIdLlanta.Text;
    int UbicacionLlanta = Convert.ToInt32(DDLUbicacionLlanta.Text);
    //Datos URL
    string Registro = Request["Registro"];
    //Convierto el dato anteior a Int
    int RegistroInt = Convert.ToInt32(Registro);
    //Obtengo el dato Equipo
    var q1 = cliente.GetLlantasSalidasRegistroAsync(RegistroInt).Result;
    string Equipo = q1.[equipo];

    //Identificamos si hay datos en la base de datos.
    var q2 = cliente.GetLlantasValidacionUltimoRegistroAsync(Equipo, IdLlanta, UbicacionLlanta).Result;
    //Validamos de acuerdo al contenidido, si existen registros activos.
    args.IsValid = (q2.Count == 0);
}
```

Pensemos que al hacer la siguiente línea, íbamos a obtener el dato del campo, el cual debe ser un único dato.

```
string Equipo = q1.[equipo];
```

Ya con este dato, procederíamos a ingresarlo a nuestra consulta q2 asi:

```
//Identificamos si hay datos en la base de datos.
    var q2 = cliente.GetLlantasValidacionUltimoRegistroAsync(Equipo, IdLlanta, UbicacionLlanta).Result;
    //Validamos de acuerdo al contenidido, si existen registros activos.
    args.IsValid = (q2.Count == 0);
```

Pero a pesar de ello, nos esta apareciendo el siguiente error:

> CS0103 The name 'equipo' does not exist in the current context

Para validar que el web API esta funcionando bien, le ingreso un registro y me entrega estos datos:

```
 [
  {
    "registro": 1020,
    "equipo": "CR-07",
    "bodega": 1200,
    "nom_bodega": "ALMACEN LORICA",
    "cod_familia": 1172,
    "familia": "RODAJE",
    "fecha": "2021-02-28T00:00:00",
    "codigo": "322373",
    "descripcion": "LLANTA 12R22.5 RADIAL TRACCION  MARCA KUMHO DISEÑO KMD01",
    "tipo_salida": "SA",
    "tipo": "SILO",
    "numero": 2925,
    "cantidad": 4,
    "costo": 1247032.48,
    "total_costo": 4988129.92,
    "destino": "2.001.935",
    "horometro": "13418",
    "adicional": "H13418/ 110081 110074 110087 110086",
    "horometro_ingresado": "13395.00",
    "empresa": "Construcciones el Condor S.A.",
    "fechaInsert": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

De esta forma valido que el web API esta funcionado bien.

Agradecemos sus indicaciones para poder utilizar el campo equipo.

Comment: ¿Seguro que `equipo` es un `int` para que sea extraído mediante `string Equipo = q1.[equipo];` ? ¿No será algún numerito tipo 0,1,2... donde quedaría `string Equipo = q1.[0];` ?

Comment: Hola fredyfx, equipo es es un string. La consulta:  var q1 = cliente.GetLlantasSalidasRegistroAsync(RegistroInt).Result; devuelve una lista con una sola fila y con varios campos. Yo solo deseo obtener el campo equipo para luego introducirlo en el otro metodo, el cual recibe un parametro llamado Equipo, el cual debe ser de tipo string.

Comment: `q1.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.equipo == equipo)`

Comment: Hola Yussef, acabo de implementar el código así: string Equipo = q1.FirstOrDefault(a => a.equipo == equipo); y me sale el siguienter error: CS1061 'LlanSalidasLlantas' does not contain a definition for 'equipo' and no accessible extension method 'equipo' accepting a first argument of type assembly reference?. Luego de validar  'LlanSalidasLlantas', se confirma que tiene el parametro equipo del tipo string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo, de esta forma logramos corregir los errores que se estaban presentando, procedemos con la explicación:

La idea inicial era obtener el campo "equipo" del lado del cliente web API, pero vimos como mejor opción, hacer un método en el web API que luego fuera invocado en el cliente.
El método que creamos en el web API fue esta:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Validacion/Ultimo/Registro", Name = "GetLlantasValidacionUltimoRegistro")]
    public List<LlanHistoria> GetLlantasValidacionUltimoRegistro(int Registro, string? Id, int Ubicacion)
    {
        try
        {
            // 2024-02-27: Obtengo el equipo.
            var t1 = GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro);
            var q1 = t1.FirstOrDefault();
            string? Equipo = q1.equipo;
            // 2024-02-08: Obtengo el ultimo registro de la llanta.
            var t2 = GetLlantasValidacionDuplicidad(Id);
            // 2024-02-08: Valido si el ultimo registro de la llanta cumple con el equipo y la ubicacion.
            var q2 = from a in t2
                    where
                        a.equipo == Equipo
                        &&
                        a.Ubicacion == Ubicacion
                    select new LlanHistoria
                    {
                        id = a.id,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        Ubicacion = a.Ubicacion,
                        prof_1 = a.prof_1,
                        Horometro = a.Horometro,
                        Odometro = a.Odometro,
                        Fecha = a.Fecha
                    };
            return q2.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return LlanHistoriaExcepcion;
        }
    }
```

Un punto que fue clave fue el entender que luego de tener una lista, la puedo invocar en otro método. Fue así que de esta forma pude obtener el dato equipo que tanto necesitaba, lo cual fue logrado en estas líneas:

```
var t1 = GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(Registro);
            var q1 = t1.FirstOrDefault();
            string? Equipo = q1.equipo;
```

Luego del lado del cliente web API, invoque a este nuevo método así:

```
protected void CVUbicacionLlanta_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    // Datos cliente
    string IdLlanta = TBIdLlanta.Text;
    int UbicacionLlanta = Convert.ToInt32(DDLUbicacionLlanta.Text);
    // Datos URL
    string Registro = Request["Registro"];
    // Convierto el dato anteior a Int
    int RegistroInt = Convert.ToInt32(Registro);
    var q2 = cliente.GetLlantasValidacionUltimoRegistroAsync(RegistroInt, IdLlanta, UbicacionLlanta).Result;
    // Validamos de acuerdo al contenidido, si existen registros activos.
    args.IsValid = (q2.Count == 0);
}
```